# Perl/Windows: commandline program execution error: "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process "

Tags: windows, perl, shell, batch-file

I'm trying to execute 2 windows programs from a perl. I don't need any output from them into the perl and I need keep perl running after it, so my best approach is use system

(part of the code)

```
######  Exec 1.exe and 2.exe  ################################################
system(1,"1.exe" );
system(1,"2.exe data.tmp");
```

The 2.exe returs always: "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" but the script works.

1.exe works perfectly.

I've tried:
  ######  Exec 1.exe and 2.exe  #################################
    system("start /b 1.exe");
    system("start /b 2.exe data.tmp");

Same result.

Also tried to create a bat that launches 1.exe and 2.exe

```
######  Exec 1.exe and 2.exe  ################################################
system(1,"start /b 1.bat");
```

Again.. same result.

I just need to execute `1.exe` and `2.exe` and obtain `data.tmp` and follow the rest of the script.

Comment: are you able to run 2.exe from the command prompt w/o that error?

Comment: `system(1,...)` does not wait for the spawn process to end. So, if your script is trying to access the data.tmp file (so it seems from your question), it may block 2.exe so it can not open the file.

Comment: I'm able to execute 1.exe and 2.exe data.tmp separately without issues on command line. 1.exe and 2.exe are totally independent each other.

Comment: Notice that 2.exe tmp.data when is called by perl hangs.. (almost output error and there is nothing in tmp.data). But running directly in windows works perfecly

Comment: Have you verified which file is "being used"? [Sysinternals' procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) might help you identify which file is in use and thus give you a clue as to what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `1.exe` uses `data.tmp` and thus blocks it for `2.exe`.

You are using `system(1, )`. That does not wait for the process to end at all. You could try without the `1` to wait for each System call to end. Under normal conditions that should fix your problem.

```
system("1.exe" );
system(1, "2.exe data.tmp");
```

If you did need to execute something while `1.exe` executes, just wait for `1.exe` to complete before starting `2.exe`:

```
my $pid = system(1, "1.exe");
... do things while 1.exe runs ...
waitpid($pid, 0);
system(1, "2.exe data.tmp");
```

This gives you way more control over what happens at which time.

Comment: Not enough arguments for waitpid at config.pl line 74, near "$pid;" .. this is what this code gaves on my perl

Comment: My bad, i forgot a 0. But if 1.exe never touches data.tmp, this will not help you anyways. And if it does, removing the `1,` from your system commands should suffice.

Comment: Your recommendation to use `fork` makes no sense. The whole point of `system(1, ...)` is to provide an alternative to the `fork` emulation on Windows. Fixed.

Comment: Hmm, not arguing over the clear improvement in quality your edit brought to my unorganized chatter. But i would still suggest using `fork()` instead of `system (1,)`. I was not aware that `System (1,)` was created to dodge `fork()` on Windows but with the greatly improved fork-emulation of today, i would argue it is not really that useful anymore. It offers less functionality than `fork()` on Windows and needlessly hinders portability. I know my post was in a bad state and i do not mind the edit at all, but i still think using `fork()` is superior to `system(1,)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `1.exe` creates `data.tmp`? The problem is that `1.exe` is not done with `data.tmp` before `2.exe` tries to access it.

If you're ok with waiting for `1.exe` to complete before launching `2.exe`, you can use any of the following:

1. Wait for `2.exe` to complete before moving on in the main program:

   ```
   system("1.exe");
   system("2.exe data.tmp");
   ```
2. Wait for `1.exe` to complete before moving on in the main program:

   ```
   system("1.exe");
   system(1, "2.exe data.tmp");  # Don't wait for 2.exe to complete
   ```
3. Don't wait at all before moving on in the main program:

   ```
   system(1, "1.exe & 2.exe data.tmp");  # Don't wait for this to complete
   ```